# How pass select data from View to JS with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m working in Angular and I have fields to fill like

I fill my select list as:

```
   function cargarCatalogo() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogos/",
                null,
                function(res) {
                    //console.log(res.data);.
                    $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
                    $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];
                },
                errorCatalogo);
        }
```

I want to know how can I pass selected Value into url in my funcion:

```
     function actualizar(vehiculo) {
                $scope.vehiculo.Origen = $scope.usuario.Origen;
                $scope.vehiculo.Version = $scope.Version;

                apiService.post("../../api/AddCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID,
                    function(res) {
                  // my code
```

How can I pass that selected value as a selected.ID, chrome console throw me

> ReferenceError: selected is not defined

View:

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-init="Catalogos[0]" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos">

  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: It should be `$scope.selected`

Comment: I try it but I get , [object%20Object] @PankajParkar

Comment: Can you please provide a working code example on jsFiddle or plnkr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$scope.selected` as `ng-model` value

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-change="filtro(selected)" 
    ng-init="Catalogos[0]" ng-model="selected" 
    ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos">
```

It should solve your problem. And the best practise is to name the controller and use `ng-model = "ctrlName.selected"`